# Using getResourceAsStream to read an Android file using his full-path

Tags: java, android, inputstream, absolute-path

I am trying to use
 `InputStream resourceAsStream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("file:///data/data/com.mysociety.myapp.debug/files/picture.jpg");` 
to put the stream of picture.jpg into resourceAsStream variable, but this returns `null` as it doesnt't find the file.

I tried by removing `file://`, and `.debug` in the path, but it also doesn't work. (the path given by Android Studio Device File Explorer is "/data/data/com.mysociety.myapp.debug/files/picture.jpg")

Do you have any idea ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `openInputStream("picture.jpg")` — called on some `Context`, such as your activity — to open an `InputStream` on a file at that location.

Or, use `new FileInputStream(new File(getFilesDir(), "picture.jpg"))`, if you prefer, where `getFilesDir()` is also a method on `Context`.

These would be the opposite of how you put the file there in the first place (e.g., you used `openOutputStream()` or `new FileOutputStream()`).

Comment: Thanks. I finally used the function getFilesDir() that you gave me to get the good path (thought the path I gived was the good one, but it wasn't) to load te file using an external library !.